# Recibo undefined en la consola

Tags: javascript, array

No se cual es mi error, soy nuevo y estoy practicando pero no me sale.

Me pide que haga una funcion que tome un array le pregunte a cada elelemnto si es positivo, negativo o cero y devuelva un array con los porcentajes de los elementos que son positivos, negativos o cero.

Esto es lo que hice:

```
function masMenos(miArray){
    var positivos =  0;
    var negativos =  0;
    var ceros = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++){
    if (miArray[i] >0){
      positivos++;
    } else if (miArray[i]<0){
        negativos++;
      } else {
        ceros++;
      }
  return masMenos[positivos/miArray.length,ceros/miArray.length,negativos/miArray.length]
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error tienes con este código o qué resultado te esta devolviendo?

Comment: cuando escribo en la terminal me dice undefined

Comment: Consejo en los títulos de tus preguntas es mucho mas efectivo colocar el error en lugar de otras cosas

Comment: ok gracias lo voy a romar ne cuneta

Comment: Como consejo, no llames a la variable de resultado que vas a devolver en el return, con el nombre de la función. Puedes equivocar fácilmente los corchetes por paréntesis y definir una recursividad sin salida...

Comment: dale muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la llave del for, la cierras después del return. Además no defines bien la cadena que devuelve el return:

```js
data = [1,2,3,-1,-1,0]; 
function masMenos(miArray){   
  var positivos =  0;   
  var negativos =  0;   
  var ceros = 0;   
  for(var i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++){
    if (miArray[i] >0)
      positivos++;
    else if (miArray[i]<0)
      negativos++;
    else 
      ceros++;        
  }   
  const porcentajes = [positivos/miArray.length,ceros/miArray.length,negativos/miArray.length]; 
  return porcentajes;  
} 

console.log(masMenos(data))
```

Comment: lo probe y me sigue dando  mal

Comment: He añadido el código de definición del array y en la llamada de la función por si ese fuese tu fallo

Comment: me sigue diciendo que esta mal

Comment: Ejecutándolo aquí está bien, ¿seguro que no tienes un error en otra parte?

Comment: ahora si me dio bien +, muchas gracias. mi problema era que después de los paréntesis en if ponía {}.

Answer (score 1):

Considero que puedes replantearlo y hacerlo de esta forma:

- Obnteniendo por dentro la longitud del vector pasado como argumento (que después usaremos para nuestra regla de 3)
- En 3 condicionales dentro de un for verificando si el elemento obtenido del vector por cada iteración es mayor a 0, menor a 0 o igual a 0
- Declaramos a nivel de contexto de la función 3 vectores vacíos que llenaremos con sus respectivoss valores, según los valores recuperados por cada condicional
- Con tres variables inicialmente declaradas con 0, igualarlas con una regla de 3 para obtener el porcentaje de cada grupo, esto lo haremos dentro de cada uno de los condicionales
- Hacer un return de las 3 variables mencionadas justo antes de que la función cierre y lo colocamos dentro de un *template string* para poder recuperar e imprimir el valor de las 3 variables

Código:

```js
    function detectaElementos(vector) {
      let positivos = []
      let negativos = []
      let ceros     = []
      let totalElementos = vector.length
      let res1 = 0
      let res2 = 0
      let res3 = 0
      
      for(i = 0; i<vector.length; i++) {
        if(vector[i] >= 1) {
          positivos.push(vector[i]) 
          res1 = (positivos.length * 100) / totalElementos
        }
        if(vector[i] === 0) {
          ceros.push(vector[i])
          res2 = (ceros.length * 100) / totalElementos
        }
        if(vector[i] < 0) {
          negativos.push(vector[i])
          res3 = (negativos.length * 100) / totalElementos
        }
      }
      return `Porcentaje de positivos: ${res1} Porcentaje de ceros: ${res2} y Porcentaje de negativos: ${res3}`
    }
    
    console.log(detectaElementos([1, 2, 0, 1]))
```

Con una salida que para este caso diría algo asi:

> "Porcentaje de positivos: 75 Porcentaje de ceros: 25 y Porcentaje de negativos: 0"

Comment: gracias por la ayuda pero ya lo puede resolver. Ademas se ve un poco mas complicado y te pide los porentajes en decimales. Igual voy a analizar tu repsuesta porque me intersa entederla mejor.